# Furigana JS is not served over HTTPS

Tags: bug, status-completed, furigana

If you browse JLSE on HTTPS, the furigana JS doesn't load.

This is because the furigana JS is served as `http://sstatic.net/js/third-party/japanese-l-u.js?v=6` instead of as `https:// ...`

Since `sstatic.net` seems to support HTTPS just fine, I think this should probably not be too difficult to fix for whoever is responsible for these sort of things.

Comment: FWIW, HTTPS still isn't fully supported on Stack Exchange.  I know this because recently someone accidentally enabled HTTPS on Stack Exchange in the HTTPS Everywhere plugin, and people complained about not being able to use the site: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214968/cant-login-with-stack-exchange-openid-when-https-everywhere-plugin-is-active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This specific JS file is now being served via a schemaless URL, meaning it works for http and https.

Comment: It's working, thanks!

Comment: @Oded Do you think you could serve the file from cdn.sstatic.net instead of sstatic.net?  See [this bug report](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/furigana-possibly-broken-in-firefox-29-0#comment3021_1229).